# What all are considered in the Class scope?

Tags: c++, class, scope

Just trying to grab the concept revolving around the scope of the Class in C++. If we take an example something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string barValue="OUTSIDE CLASS";

class foo
{
    public:
        void print_bar()
        {
            cout<<barValue<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.print_bar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering:

1. Is the `barValue` variable is in the Class scope?
2. Can the `barValue` be accepted even if it is defined in one of the included files?
3. Is the file and all the included files can be called as the scope of the `foo` Class?
4. I can understand that the `barValue` will not be considered if it is defined after the Class body. To follow up is that means all the included files comes before the Class body and in general before the current file content?

Comment: What do you mean by "accepted"?

Comment: @NathanPierson By accepted I mean that it has been found declared by the `foo` class and by the `print_bar` function definition to be specific

Comment: (1) Declared at class scope - no. Visible at class scope - yes. Normally I'd understand "at class scope" to mean the former. (4) Yes, includes normally come before everything else.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if you say so, then my question could be better formed like what is the visibility scope of the Class?

Comment: It's complicated. Normally you can access everything above the class, excluding function-local variables and private variables of non-friend classes. Templates also can sometimes [access things below themselves](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

> Is the barValue variable is in the class scope?

`barValue` is a **global variable** since you have defined it outside any function and class. Therefore `barValue` can be used inside the class as you did.

**Question 2**

> Can the barValue be accepted even if it is defined in one of the included files?

Yes even if `barValue` is defined in a header file it can be used in other files because/if it has **external linkage** as shown in the below example.

**file.h**

```
int barvalue = 34;//barvalue has external linkage
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout<<barvalue<<std::endl;//prints 34
    return 0;
}
```

**Question 3**

> Is the file and all the included files can be called as the scope of the foo class?

No

**Question 4**

> I can understand that the `barValue` will not be considered if it is defined after the class body. To follow up is that means all the included files comes before the Class body and in general before the current file content?

You should clarify this question more because i think it is not clear what your are asking here but i will try to answer what i understand from your question.

If you define `barValue` after the class `foo` definition then the program will not work because since you have defined it after the class definition, therefore it has not been defined/declared at the point when you write `cout<<barValue<<endl;`  which is what the error says as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class foo
{
    public:
        void print_bar()
        {
            cout<<barValue<<endl;//error: ‘barValue’ was not declared in this scope
        }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.print_bar();
    return 0;
}
string barValue="OUTSIDE CLASS";
```